# Convert a div text to a dropdown and the div text is the selected option

Tags: javascript

The text of a div needs to become the selected option of a generated select dropdown. I successfully create the dropdown and replace the div but, the value given to set the selected option does not become selected.

Below, is how I'm getting the div value and how I'm creating the dropdown

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = document.getElementById("val_to_set");

 var rvalue = d.innerHTML;    //Getting the value of div

//The options of a dropdown are populated from another dropdown menu 

 var listOptions =  document.getElementById("dropdown");

 var newddown = '<select name="displayoption">'+listOptions.innerHTML+'</select>';

 //Replace the div with the created dropdown menu 

d.innerHTML = newddown;    //TARGET ELEMENT

</script>
```

I found this link that explains how to select by value, text or index

[1] http://www.daftlogic.com/information-programmatically-preselect-dropdown-using-javascript.htm

When trying to get the options of new created dropdown I get "options is undefined"

The new dropdown will not select the given option - I have tried all cases in the given link to include adding the following lines before I replace div with the dropdown.

```
var seeker = ">"+rvalue+"<";
newddown = newddown.replace(seeker, "selected"+seeker);
```

What I'm I doing wrong? I am a beginner with jQuery and I would like to stick with JavaScript.

**EDITED - Included dropdown used to populate options of target element**

```
<select id="dropdown" name="listedoptions" >
<?php

echo "    <option value=''></option>  \n";
          $ores = sqlStatement("SELECT option_id, title, is_default FROM list_options" .
                  " WHERE list_id = 'adjreason'  ORDER BY seq, title");

            while ($orow = sqlFetchArray($ores)) {
            echo "    <option value='" . $orow['option_id']). "'";
            echo ">" . $orow['title'] . "</option>\n";
            } 
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Please can you include your markup for the target html?

Comment: I edited the content to include the target element  d.innerHTML = newddown;

Comment: You are getting the innerHTML of a "select" (only the list of "options").  If the menu is supposed to be as selectable as an ordinary "select" object, perhaps you should get the outerHTML instead, so that the "select" object is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example using your code and some sample options:

http://jsfiddle.net/m6y3mgky/

Instead of replacing the text, it's very easy to iterate over the options and programmatically select the correct one, this is as per the article you referenced. This is also less prone to errors.

```
var opts = d.childNodes[0].options;
for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    if (opts[i].value == rvalue) {
        opts[i].selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `d` references the <div>, not the <select> node, this is because you are using `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for your input mikeapr4! This childNodes did the trick :)